# Using boto to download a file from GCS sometimes results in a partial file

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, boto

I have a very simple function that uses boto to grab files from a bucket in GCS.

```
def copy_from_gcs(src_path, dst_path):
    """Copies the file at src_path in GCS to dst_path locally"""

    logging.info("Copying GCS path %s to %s", src_path, dst_path)
    uri = boto.storage_uri(src_path, "gs")
    with open(dst_path, "w") as dst_file:
        uri.get_key().get_file(dst_file)
```

This nearly always works just fine.  But roughly 1 time in 10,000 this function will exit successfully and the file it creates will be truncated.  That is, as much of the file that gets downloaded is correct and matches the file in GCS, but only the first part of the file. No exception is thrown, and I don't see any relevant messages in my log.

Am I doing something dumb?  Should this work?  Is this a known problem with boto? (I've searched, but have so far come up empty.)

Note that this is happening in one of many Processes created with the multiprocessing library, but this work is always done within a single process, and no boto objects are passed between processes. So I don't think the fact that boto isn't thread safe is causing my problems, though I'd be happy to to be told I'm wrong about that.

I am using boto 2.45.0, python 2.7.9 on Debian 8.7.

Comment: Whoever do this using boto should deserved a slap on the wrist. USE BOTO3!

Comment: @mootmoot Does boto3 have better error handling?  Will it solve my problem?

Comment: Honestly, boto API is not mean for Google cloud platform, it is not officially supported by boto team. I will correct my comment : using boto3 will not fix your issue either.  Use Google cloud own api.